# Add - instead of white spaces in url rewriting

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have this url:

```
http://www.site.com/en/about.php?id=112&name=andrew marshall dickens
```

and i would like to rewrite it like this:

```
http://www.site.com/112/andrew-marshall-dickens.html
```

so far:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /en/about.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

I'm having trouble with the '-' character.Any suggestions ? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['name'])` in `about.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're attempting to use a Regex to remove characters from the middle of a string which could have any number of that character in it in the middle of a RewriteRule. On one hand that's not really possible, on the other hand, you're passing the ID in, so I assume you can get the name using the id in your PHP script, so there's not really a need to parse the name from the URL variables, and as a 3rd option, why not just str_replace the - characters in PHP and ucwords() the string before outputting it if you want to use the name variable?

Comment: i would like to add the name parameter for SEO reasons. is there any other solution to add the name to the url ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. You can add the name to the SEO url for SEO purposes, but that doesn't mean you need to parse it back into your PHP script, and if you're relying on that data in your script, I would not parse it.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /en/about.php?id=$1 [L] would be much more efficient and you can use the ID parameter in PHP to read the name from your DB so that someone can not alter the URL and change the output of the page. So the URL site.com/112/andrew-marshall-dickens.html would point to the same page as site.com/112/suck-my-balls.html and even though someone changed the URL, your page would still say "Andrew Marshall Dickens" instead of "Suck My Balls". Preventing someone from maliciously rewriting URLS and posting them on sites giving you a bad reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to pass name param because id can get that.

Anyway:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)\.html$ /en/about.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

But hey, reading the comment, i just realized: what's your problem? Your regex should already work